# JS - Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to convert the image to **base64**, and send image to server, but at the moment I am getting following error:

```
app.js:503 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Line 503 is

```
let image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The code in question:

```
let theId = $('.rev_slider').attr('id')

let container = document.getElementById(theId);

$('#download-file').click(function () {
    html2canvas(container, { allowTaint: true }).then(function (canvas) {

        let templateData = $('#ds-slide')

        let image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")
        let title = templateData.data('title')

        console.log(canvas);


        $.post("/downloads/store", {
            image: image,
            title: title,
            templateID: templateData.data('templateid')
        },
            function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                let a = document.createElement('a')

                a.href = data.url;
                a.download = title + '.jpeg';

                document.body.append(a);

                a.click();
                a.remove();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data.url);

            },
            "json"
        );



    });

});
```

Comment: The error means that the `<img>` tag "src" is from a different domain, so the browser will not allow code from your domain to extract the image content.

Comment: But the img tag isn't created anywhere.

Comment: Right, it usually involves an `<img>`, but nevertheless that's what the error means. The browser considers something on the page (the content that you're rendering into the `<canvas>`) to be from another domain, which "taints" the canvas. It's a security measure.

Comment: Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: [Perhaps this Github issue and its discussion may help.](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1614)